# How to stop event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

consider following,

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit"/>            
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>         
        $("#txt1").live("blur", function () {
            console.log('blur');            
            return false;
        });

        $("#btn1").live("click", function () {
            console.log('click');
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Above code will log blur event and click event on trigger of respective events.
If click or change something in text box and then click on button btn1 blur and click event will happen respectively.What i want is if blur event is happening because of btn1 then click event should not happen,it should log only blur event,I want to stop click event from happening.
How to do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: see my (@user2727841) answer and link... If it fulfil your requirement then vote it for others for reference....

Comment: Ok your problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/xA82k/) is one way to solve it by adding a timeout.

```
var inFocus = false;

$("#txt1").focus(function () {
    inFocus = true;
    $("#log").prepend("<p>focus</p>");

});
$("#txt1").blur(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){inFocus = false;},200);
    $("#log").prepend("<p>blur</p>");
});
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    if (!inFocus) {
        $("#log").prepend("<p>click</p>");
    }
});
```

In the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/xA82k/), I put the log out to the window.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="txt1" />
      <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit"/>            
   </div>
</form>
```

javascript code

```
$("#txt1").on("blur", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('blur');            
   return false;
});
$("#btn1").on("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('click');
   return false;
});
```

also test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JQ4B8/) and remember `live` keyword is deprectaed from jquery 1.9 use `on` instead of `live` in jquery 1.9 or greater.

Comment: Thanxx,this works,but due to some compatibility issues I can't use 'on' function.So I can't refer to event.

Comment: And it's not working with console.log.

Comment: its working with console and for that you've see it in console.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "stop" an other/foreign event like so. `Event.preventDefault()` and/or `Event.stopPropagation()` (which both will get triggered when returning `false` from within a jQuery event handler), will allow you to stop and prevent the exact same event from further processing on parent nodes.

In your instance, you need your own logic. Use some variables and set them properly and check the value where necessary. For instance, on click you set `FOOBAR = true` and in `blur` you check `if( FOOBAR )` and act on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy one event see the demo

Hope this helps you.

jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/5a86V

Comment: I think your page has been removed.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/5a86V/

Comment: Rahul,thanks for your response,but it will destroy click event permanently,and I don't want that.